# How to join data from multiple netCDF files with xarray in Python?

Tags: python, concatenation, netcdf, python-xarray

I'm trying to open multiple netCDF files with xarray in Python. The files have data with same shape and I want to join them, creating a new dimension.

I tried to use concat_dim argument for xarray.open_mfdataset(), but it doesn't work as expected. An example is given below, which open two files with temperature data for 124 times, 241 latitudes and 480 longitudes:

```
DS = xr.open_mfdataset( 'eraINTERIM_t2m_*.nc', concat_dim='cases' )
da_t2m = DS.t2m

print( da_t2m )
```

With this code, I expect that the result data array will have a shape like (cases: 2, time: 124, latitude: 241, longitude: 480). However, its shape was (cases: 2, time: 248, latitude: 241, longitude: 480).
It creates a new dimension, but also sums the leftmost dimension: 'time' dimension of two datasets.
I was wondering whether it's an error from 'xarray.open_mfdateset' or it's an expected behavior because 'time' dimension is UNLIMITED for both datasets.

Is there a way to join data from these files directly using xarray and get the above expected return?

Thank you.

Mateus

Comment: Are the time dimensions the same (i.e. both files contain data for the same time range)?

Comment: The time dimension has same length in both files, 124 time indexes. However, they don't cover the same time period.

Comment: Xarray is attempting to align your data along the existing time dimension. What would you like your time coordinate to be after xarray concatenates the individual datasets?

Comment: If you think about different cases or events with different time periods (but equal in length), you may have an large array with data for different events, which each event having its own duration. So, the resultant array would have an additional dimension: events.

Comment: @Mateus You could try to rename/copy/drop the time dimension with a new new dimension which is equal for each file (just 0,1,..., 123). This could be done via open_mfdataset's `preprocess` keyword argument. 
I'm doing something similar, but do not have the code at hand atm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extending from my comment I would try this:

```
def preproc(ds):
    ds = ds.assign({'stime': (['time'], ds.time)}).drop('time').rename({'time': 'ntime'})
    # we might need to tweak this a bit further, depending on the actual data layout
    return ds

DS = xr.open_mfdataset( 'eraINTERIM_t2m_*.nc', concat_dim='cases', preprocess=preproc)
```

The good thing here is, that you keep the original time coordinate in `stime` while renaming the original dimension (`time` -> `ntime`).

If everything works well, you should get resulting dimensions as (`cases`, `ntime`, `latitude`, `longitude`).

Disclaimer: I do similar in a loop with a final concat (wich works very well), but did not test the `preprocess`-approach.

Comment: Thank you @kmuehlbauer! Your code works very well, including saving dates in `stime` varible.

Comment: Kudos to all those people doing great work under the PyData umbrella. These packages (eg. pandas, xarray etc.) really improved my workflows.

Answer (score 1):

The result makes sense if the times are different.

To simplify it, forget about the lat-lon dimension for a moment and imagine you have two files that are simply data at 2 timeslices.  The first has data at timesteps 1,2  and the second file with timesteps of 3 and 4.   You can't create a combined dataset with a time dimension that only spans 2 timeslices; the time dimension variable has to have the times 1,2,3,4.  So if you say you want a new dimension "cases", then the data is then combined as a 2d array and would look like this:

```
times: 1,2,3,4

cases: 1,2

data: 
               time
          1    2    3    4
cases 1:  x1   x2 
      2:            x3   x4
```

Think of the netcdf file that would be the equivalent, the time dimension has to span the range of values present in both files.  The only way you could combine two files and get (cases: 2, time: 124, latitude: 241, longitude: 480) would be if both files have the same time, lat AND lon values, i.e. point to exactly the same region in time-lat-lon space.

ps: Somewhat off-topic for the question, but if you are just starting a new analysis, why not instead switch to the new generation, higher resolution ERA-5 reanalysis, which is now available back to 1979 too (and eventually will be extended further back), you can download it straight to your desktop with the python api scripts from here:

https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/search?type=dataset

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @AdrianTompkins and @jhamman. After your comments I realize that due different time periods I really can't get what I want, with xarray.

My main purpose to create such array is to get in one single N-D array all data for different events, with same time duration. Thus, I can get easily, for example, composite fields of all events for each time (hour, day, etc).

I'm trying to do the same as I do with NCL. See below a code for NCL that works as expected (for me) for the same data:

```
f = addfiles( (/"eraINTERIM_t2m_201812.nc", "eraINTERIM_t2m_201901.nc"/), "r" )
ListSetType( f, "join" )
temp = f[:]->t2m
printVarSummary( temp )
```

The final result is an array with 4 dimensions, with the new one automatically named as **ncl_join**.

However, NCL doesn't respect time axis, joins the arrays and gives to the resulting time axis the coordinates of the first file. So, time axis become useless.

However, as well said for @AdrianTompkins, the time periods are different and xarray can't join data like this. So, to create such array, in Python with xarray, I think the only way is to delete time coordinate from arrays. Thus, time dimension would have only integer indexes.

The array given by xarray works like @AdrianThompkins said in his small example. Since it keep time coordinates for all merged data, I think xarray solution is the correct one, in comparison with NCL. But, now I think that a computation of composites (getting same example given above) wouldn't be done as easyly as it seems with NCL.

In a small test, I print two values from merged array with xarray with

```
print( da_t2m[ 0, 0, 0, 0 ].values )
print( da_t2m[ 1, 0, 0, 0 ].values )
```

What results in

```
252.11412
nan
```

For the second case, there isn't data for the first time, as expected.

**UPDATE**: all answers help me to understand better this problem, so I had to  add an update here to also thanks @kmuehlbauer for his answer, indicating that his code give the expected array.

Again, thank you all for help!

Mateus

Comment: I see, why don't you read in each file separately in a loop and place the data into a 4D numpy array in that case, rather than using the xarray concat function?

Comment: I'm just trying to avoid loops, using this xarray capability. But, I think that I'll not be able to. Thanks.